# Forecast future values from FFT

Tags: matlab

In the attached code I create an arbitrarily complex signal generator (3 sine waves in this case) and generate 256 + 50 values using it. I then create an FFT using the first 256 values, plot them and then do an inverse FFT and verify that it produces a very close representation of the original signal. All good so far.

What I'd like to do now is, using the FFT results, attempt to generate the additional 50 values that were not part of the FFT data set. Is there a straight-forward in MatLab?

Without being exactly sure how I assume I can create a signal generator using the center frequency of each bin and the FFT result and generate the signal that way, but that does seem like a lot of work so before I went down that path I figured I'd see if there was an easy way that I just haven't found.

I have MatLab & the Signal Processing and DSP packages to use at this time.

Thanks!

```
FFTsize = 256;
futureSize = 50;
t = 1:FFTsize+futureSize;

F1_bars = 10;
RadPerBar1 = (2*pi)/F1_bars;
L1 = 1;
Offset1 = 0;

F2_bars = 8;
RadPerBar2 = (2*pi)/F2_bars;
L2 = 1;
Offset2 = 0;

F3_bars = 50;
RadPerBar3 = (2*pi)/F3_bars;
L3 = 1;
Offset3 = 0;

Sig = (L1*sin(RadPerBar1*t + Offset1) +...
       L2*sin(RadPerBar2*t + Offset2) +...
       L3*sin(RadPerBar3*t + Offset3));


DataSet = Sig(1:FFTsize);

FFT = fft(DataSet)/FFTsize;
%Suggested by Mad Physicist 
paddedFFT = [FFT(1:ceil(FFTsize/2)) zeros(1, futureSize) FFT(ceil(FFTsize/2)+1 : end)];

IFFT = ifft(FFT)*FFTsize;
%Suggested by Mad Physicist 
IFFT2 = ifft(paddedFFT)*(FFTsize + futureSize);

figure(111);
hold off;
plot(abs(FFT));
hold on;
plot(abs(paddedFFT),'--r');
legend('FFT','Padded FFT','Position','best');
hold off;

figure(110)
hold off;
plot(Sig);
hold on;
plot(IFFT,'--r');
plot(t, IFFT2,'g');
legend('Input Signal','IFFT','Padded IFFT','Position','best');
hold off;
```

Comment: I am not perfectly sure if this is even possible in this specific way, as just doing DFT and IDFT simply assumes periodic signals. In the meantime I think [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-i-extrapolate-a-1d-signal) might be a good starting point. By the way: Please **do not edit your original code using suggestions from answers**, as this will change the question you are asking!

Comment: Point taken on the code edits. I wasn't sure how to ask Mad Physicist whether I had implemented his idea correctly? Are code blocks insertable in comments? WRT the link, it's a _very_ interesting way to go, does seem to work and it may be what I end up doing. It will take some more study on my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pad the FFT with 50 zeros before you invert it:

```
futureSize = 50;
paddedFFT = [FFT(1:ceil(FFTsize/2)) zeros(1, futureSize) FFT(ceil(FFTsize/2)+1 : end)];
IFFT = ifft(paddedFFT)*(FFTsize + futureSize);
```

Comment: Boy I'd really like that to work but I don't seem to be getting it right. It appears to stretch out the original 256 byte signal to the new 306 byte range, which to me makes sense. By padding the FFT haven't we changed the bin frequencies and we're just generating the same signal more slowly? Anyway, please let me know if I've misunderstood. Thanks